# I can't seem to be able to use Google LaTex integration

Tags: google-sheets

Google claims that they have allowed [LaTex equations in Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749?hl=en#). According to the help page, the option should appear under *Insert* → *Equation*. Doesn't seem to be the case:

[image: google spreadsheet insert menu]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because the respective help page is referring to Google *Docs* (the text editor), not Google *Sheets*. And you are trying to insert it in a Google Sheets document.